# How to delete all '0's in a string in left and right in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas

I want to delete all '0's in a string in left and right in pandas dataframe.

Here's my data set:

```
Id    Label
0     000010
1     001010
2     000111
3     111100
```

Here's my expected output:

```
Id    Label      Output
0     000010          1
1     001010        101
2     000111        111
3     111100       1111
```

Based on the table above,  it is expected that any 0's in left and right are removed.

Comment: use `strip('0')`, I hope Label is object dtype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.strip`:

```
>>> df['Output'] = df['Label'].str.strip('0')
>>> df
  Id   Label Output
0  0      10      1
1  1    1010    101
2  2     111    111
3  3  111100   1111
>>>
```